# What are the design rules in iOS 11

Tags: ios

What are the design rules I should take into account when designing an iOS app using xCode 9 , that will be compatible with iOS 11 and iPhone X? I know that I should consider the safe area while designing , is there is anything else ?

Comment: See the Apple [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/themes/) for extensive guidance on designing for iOS.

Comment: Take a look at [Supporting iPhone X](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/supporting-iphone-x/).